# Ordering values to show in a hierarchy view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to order a table to show it in a hierarchy view and to have less trouble with my C# code.

I've created a simplified table to show what I'm trying to achieve: ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ad9eb/1)).

What I have:

```
| id | parent | level |
|----|--------|-------|
|  2 | (null) |     1 |
|  7 |      2 |     2 |
|  8 |      2 |     2 |
|  9 |      7 |     3 |
| 12 |      7 |     3 |
| 14 |      9 |     4 |
| 15 |     12 |     4 |
```

What I need:

```
| id | parent | level |
|----|--------|-------|
|  2 | (null) |     1 |
|  7 |      2 |     2 |
|  9 |      7 |     3 |
| 14 |      9 |     4 |
| 12 |      7 |     3 |
| 15 |     12 |     4 |
|  8 |      2 |     2 |
```

So I'll be able to get this result and directly post it like the following:

```
ID
--02
----07
------09
--------14
------12
--------15
----08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
with MyCte as
(
    select id
        , parent
        , level 
        , CAST(ID as varchar(50)) as SortOrder
        from posts 
        where parent is null
    union all
    select p.id
        , p.parent
        , p.level
        , CAST(p2.SortOrder + '.' + right('000' + CAST(p.ID as varchar(10)), 3) as varchar(50))
    from posts p
    inner join MyCte p2 on p2.Id = p.parent
)

select *, 
replicate('-', level) + cast(id as varchar(10))
from MyCte
order by SortOrder
```

Comment: Can you say what it doesn't work? Just saying it doesn't work doesn't provide much detail. Not sure why you downvoted this.

Comment: I did not down vote you (since you are trying to help me!). It does not work because it is showing the IDs in the following order: 2 / 7 / 8 / 9 / 12 / 14 / 15. I need 2 / 7 / 9 / 14 / 12 / 15 / 8

Comment: Ahh I missed the sorting within each group. We can make that work. Give me a bit and I will update my answer.

Comment: There that should do it for you. You can tweak the output to suit whatever you need.

Comment: Great! It is working now as I want. I've liked your "Sort Order" approach.